# How to build multiple process bars through a loop by using tqdm?

Tags: python, tqdm

I want to make a process bar in each iteration of the outer loop by using tqdm，but I have failed.

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in range(10):
   pbar = tqdm(total=200)
   for j in range(200):
      ...
      pbar.update(j+1)
   pbar.close()
```

At first, this code works well.

[The result of first iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFBSw.png)

After the first iteration of the outer loop, the process bar disappeared and the iteration continued.

[The result after first ieteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxBka.png)
Why the first loop doesn't make a new process bar? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to update `pbar`.

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    for j in tqdm(range(200)):
        # do something here
        time.sleep(0.01)
```